# Access Sitecore Context in Window Application

Tags: untagged

I have a requirement where I am accessing the Sitecore content tree in the Windows Console application.

The above window application will not be on the same server where the Sitecore application will be hosted. It will be deployed on another server.

My concern is how can I access the Sitecore Context as it will be null in non-Sitecore applications. Did anyone face such type of requirement or can give me an idea on how to access the Sitecore Context?